# theme_page_templates not working

Tags: filters, templates

I'm trying to filter the contents of my page template dropdown in the admin area. Having done some Googling it seems that the hook I need to use is theme_page_templates ... but this just does not run for me. I have no idea why but the code is not called at all. This is the code I'm using, but nothing happens.

```
function filter_template_dropdown( $page_templates ) {
    die( var_dump( $page_templates ) );

    // Removes item from template array.
    unset( $page_templates['template-faq.php'] );

    // Returns the updated array.
    return $page_templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'filter_template_dropdown' );
```

I'm running the latest version of Wordpress (4.7.2) - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're viewing an individual page of the `page` post type in admin when you try this? Your code works as expected for me- output is halted when the Page Attributes meta box is rendered.

Comment: Ohhh man, I'm such a noob! I was looking at a `post` not a `page`. Have just checked again and its working fine! Thanks @Milo

Answer (score 1):

The `theme_page_templates` filter is not available anymore, please use the `theme_templates` filter instead.

```php
add_filter( 'theme_templates', 'filter_template_dropdown' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to `die()` in your function, which terminates the execution of your function and outputs the $page_templates as is.

To successfully remove the `template-faq.php` from the available page templates, you should remove your call to `die()`:

```
function filter_template_dropdown( $page_templates ) {

    // Removes item from template array.
    unset( $page_templates['template-faq.php'] );

    // Returns the updated array.
    return $page_templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'filter_template_dropdown' );
```

Comment: Hi Tunji, I added the die() so I could see whether or not the function was being called. I can confirm that it doesn't work without the die() either